# Using multer and express with typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, multer

## Background

I'm making a simple website in which a user can upload an image.
I'm using Node/React/Multer/**Typescript**.

## Problem

```
app.post('/admin/uploads', async (req, res) => {
  uploadHandler(req, res, (err) => {
    ...
    if ( req.files.companyImage !== undefined ) {
      ...
    }
    res.sendStatus(201);
  });
});
```

typescript intellisense shows error like below.

```
Property 'companyImage' does not exist on type '{ [fieldname: string]: File[]; } | File[]'.
Property 'companyImage' does not exist on type '{ [fieldname: string]: File[]; }'.ts(2339)
```

But, I cannot understand why this is error. I think `files` object has type `{ [fieldname: string]: File[]; }`. This means `files` object can have property which is string.

So I test with simple example.

```
type myType = {
  [fieldName: string]: number
}

let req: myType = {
  a: 333,
  b: 344
}

console.log(req.a);
console.log(req.c); // undefined but intellisense don't show error
```

I don't know why `files` object cannot have `companyImage` property.

Check please.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I don't know if you successfully resolved your issue, but I had the same and had to explicitly tell TypeScript the type of my `req.files` property like this:

```ts
const files = req.files as { [fieldname: string]: Express.Multer.File[] };
```

Note that, since I'm using `upload.fields(...)`, I'm not specifying that `req.files` can also be a simple `Express.Multer.File[]`.

Comment: Express' has no exported member 'Multer'

Comment: `npm install --save-dev @types/multer` to have it

Comment: The reason this would resolve the issue is because the type of req.files is defined as either an object with field names OR an array. Arrays do not contain a `companyImage` property. A more correct solution (without explicit type casts) would be to check if req.files is an array first.

`const files = req.files; if(Array.isArray(files)) { throw new Error(); } else { console.log(files.companyImage) }`

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using typescript, create an interface for file as

```
interface IFile {
  fieldname: string;
  originalname: string;
  encoding: string;
  mimetype: string;
  buffer: Buffer;
  size: number;
}
```

and then declare `const files = req.files as IFile[]`
and remember to add `files: IFile;` in the types/express/index.d.ts as

```
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Request {
      files: IFile;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, I have the same issue on my TypeScript version `(^5.2.2)`. Even though I can't find any type on Multer, here I do solve my issue.

Declare namespace on global type file

```
export type IFile = {
  fieldname: string;
  originalname: string;
  encoding: string;
  mimetype: string;
  buffer: Buffer;
  size: number;
};

declare global {
  namespace Express {
    type Request = {
      files: IFile;
    };
  }
}
```

Then use them where I need with the declared type

```
const fileInfo = (req.files as { fileName?: IFile[] })['fileName']?.[0];
```

Here, `fileName` contains your `formData` file name

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by `Object.assign(req.files)` then you can deal with it as an object:
`console.log(s.image[0].path);`

Comment: The question specifically mentioned using typescript. Answers that strip types defeat the purpose of using typescript.

You can deal with req.files without stripping types, as mentioned [in another answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58357812/1979230)